Java - selecting between SocketChannel and stdin?
I'm building a Chat application in Java (educational purpose project), which is client-server architectured. It is a console application.
The client and server communicate using a TCP connection.
On the client side, I want the program to be able to receive messages from the server (when another user sends this user a message for example), but in the same time, the program should be able to take user input (for example - to send another user a message).
Ideally, I would want to use Selector to select between the socket and System.in, but from what I understand, there is no straightforward way to do this.
Any idea?

I think there is no way to use a Selector for System.in at all.  Usually in arcetectures I see one thread used for the Selector.  It receives packets and dumps them in a queue for further processing, then returns immediately to the Selector.  Another thread could listen at System.in and process user input.  If required a pool of worker threads could provide additional processing.  But I think there's no way to realistically do this without using at least two threads to process each input source.

The only things you can select on in Java are SelectableChannels, and there isn’t one for stdin.
